# Plot and non-numerical labels with PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots

Given some data (from a file), I would like to use the first two columns as coordinates, and the last column as label for every point.

```
x    y   label
123  5.2 name
```

I use the table command to read the first two columns as data:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot+[only marks,x=x, y=y, ] table {Data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The data of the second column should appear above each scatter point as simple text.

A promising option seems to be the option nodes near coords, but I don't see how I can use the data from the file and combine it with that.

[This question is similar to this post, where they had numerical values in the last column.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52038/plot-and-label-data-from-file-with-pgfplots)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`nodes near coords` prints the `meta` value for each data point, which defaults to the `y` coordinate. To print something else, you have to define what the `meta` value is. In your case, you want to provide the `meta` value explicitly for each data point (and not calculate it or use a constant value, say), so you have to set `point meta=explicit symbolic` (the `symbolic` tells PGFPlots not to pass the value through the number parser). Then you can set `meta=name` in the `\addplot table [...]` options to specify that the `meta` value should be taken from the `name` column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            nodes near coords,
            point meta=explicit symbolic
        ]
        \addplot table [meta=label] {Data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```