# Positioning of node label in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I am using pgfplot to make a 2D plot with the nodes labelled. However, some of the text labels interfere with each other as they're too close. The default positioning of text labels in pgfplot seems to be *above* the node. Is it possible to position them *beside* the node?

This is what I have (had to make the y axis semilogy to increase the spacing between points)

[image]

Here's what I want it to be (pardon my poor photoshopping skills)

[image]

The pgfplot code I am using is as described here: [Update reference labels in scatter plots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149801/update-reference-labels-in-scatter-plots)

Comment: Please supply a MWE. It will greatly help others to recreate and test your problem/solution.

Comment: `nodes near coords align=right`?

Comment: Or `every node near coord/.style={anchor=270}`

Comment: @iab: To adjust the position of each individual label, take a look at [How to display labels on points of a tikz plot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47688/how-to-display-labels-on-points-of-a-tikz-plot)

Comment: @Jake Thanks for link. It's actually what I used eventually (the second answer i.e. `\node [] at`). Offers very fine-grained control :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess `nodes near coords align=right` does what you're after.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=6cm,xmax=0.4, % these were just for the example
  nodes near coords align=right
  ]
\addplot+[nodes near coords,only marks,
  point meta=explicit symbolic]
  table[meta=label] {
x y label
0.3 0.2 [1]
0.2 0.1 [2]
 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can this be done to individual nodes you suppose? (Different from my original question I know)

Comment: @iab I don't know, to be honest.

Comment: This works for me. You're awesome.